# Sharepoint Designer 2010+ Add-In Development Not Documented

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio

Well, I've been searching for a while around the MSDN documentation, questions here and other sites and even some books but I can't find any clear reason why there isn't any information about how to develop Add-Ins (VSTO) for SharePoint Designer 2010 and recent versions.

The little info I've found about it is from the book "Professional Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer 2007" which has a chapter about developing an Add-In to export Workflows and open them in Visual Studio, but the authors state that Microsoft doesn't support these officially.

Even knowing that, the authors create the Add-In using an unofficial template for the creation of the Visual Studio solution. So my question is:

**It is still possible to develop a SharePoint Designer Add-In for versions upper to 2010? 

If so, there is any available template that can be used to create the VS project?**

Comment: You want to built something (an Add-In) for SharePoint Designer itself, or do you want to develop A Add-In Using Designer?

Comment: I want to built something for the SharePoint Designer itself. The terminology for Add-Ins and SharePoint sometimes gets tricky for me.

Comment: Microsoft is clear SPDesigner has no future. SPD2013 works in 2016 and Online... for now. So I wouldn't built a business on extending SPD. You can use VBScript to write anything on top of it.. But indeed hardly any documentation.

Comment: I'm aware of the no future of SPD, but since I have to work with it in my projects I'm searching all the little possibilities to extend its functionality to improve my personal experience using it, like adding a text beautifier o including other editor features for example. Seems I won't have any luck with this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could be my "You can use VBScript" labels me as a dinosaur.. last time I did that was in SPDesigner 2007 ...